# How to pass more than one byte

Tags: c#, named-pipes

I have two console apps that can communicate with each other with [named pipes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.pipes(v=vs.110).aspx) that can be downloaded from NuGet, I found a [small example here](https://dotnetcodr.com/2015/06/16/basics-of-working-with-pipes-in-c-net-part-1-send-and-receive-a-single-byte/) .

**Console app1:**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SendByteAndReceiveResponse();
}     

private static void SendByteAndReceiveResponse()
{
    using (NamedPipeServerStream namedPipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream("test-pipe"))
    {
        namedPipeServer.WaitForConnection();
        namedPipeServer.WriteByte(1);
        int byteFromClient = namedPipeServer.ReadByte();
        Console.WriteLine(byteFromClient);
    }
}
```

**Consoleapp2:**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{        
    ReceiveByteAndRespond();
}

  private static void ReceiveByteAndRespond()
{
    using (NamedPipeClientStream namedPipeClient = new NamedPipeClientStream("test-pipe"))
    {
        namedPipeClient.Connect();
        Console.WriteLine(namedPipeClient.ReadByte());
        namedPipeClient.WriteByte(2);
    }            
}
```

**My question:** How can I pass more than one byte or more than one variable?

Comment: Since it's a Stream: Wrap it in a StreamWriter or TextWriter. Also you should come up with some kind of protocol, e.g. prefix each packet with it's length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`Write`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.pipes.pipestream.write(v=vs.110).aspx) method to write multiple bytes. The problem is you don't know the length on the receiving side, so you have to pass that to the server.

This code is for the server. It sends bytes to the client. First it tells how many bytes are coming, then it writes the content:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
int length = bytes.Length;

byte[] lengthAsBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(length);
namedPipeServer.Write(lengthAsBytes, 0, 4); // an int is four bytes

namedPipeServer.Write(bytes, 0, length);
```

Then on the other side, first read the length, and then the content:

```
byte[] lengthAsBytes = new byte[4]; // an int is four bytes
namedPipeServer.Read(lengthAsBytes, 0, 4);

int length = BitConverter.ToInt32(lengthAsBytes, 0);

byte[] bytes = new byte[length];
namedPipeServer.Read(bytes, 0, length);
```

Comment: "an int is two bytes" ? Not last time I checked it wasn't

Comment: Ahum. I was using ushorts first to minimize overhead... I am so embarrassed now @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Answer (score 0):

You can make a `byte` type array initialize it with as many bytes as you want. Then use `namedPipeServer.Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count )` inside a loop to iterate on all the array elements.